# Why would WCKD be willing to kill the Gladers?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-maze-runner

This may have already been asked, but because WCKD wanted to save the human population but at the same time they are killing part of the population by sending in over 50 kids to the Glade and given 2 years to get out of the maze. But why would they kill the kids? they are trying to save humans so why kill them?

If the kids never fought in the Glade against the invading Grievers, and if the Gladers stayed, would they all have died?
A bit of clarification would be nice thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The children are mostly immune to a disease,  a virus, that WCKD created. This immunity only comes from active mental activity, mainly survival type thinking, i.e. a deadly maze. That brain activity produces an enzyme in the kill zone part of the brain that makes them immune. In the books, WCKD needs the perfect brain of the best child to dissect and study to make everyone immune and end the virus. In the movies, they need to drain the children like blood donors to produce the cure en mass.

To WCKD, the children are nothing but collateral damage in their effort to save and control the population from their own mistake. Lab rats in a maze.